Sharepoint List Rule - Change Person who 'Added Item'
I have created a sharepoint list that uses power automate to collect response for MS forms.
One of the columns in the list is 'Created By' as default.
The Rules to send notification from the list had originally sent the message as '[Created By] has added a new item'.
Now after setting up the flow, it says 'Kristy (Me) has added a new item' - for ALL the items (even ones I have not created).
How do I fix this and change the person in the email to the actual submitter, not just me.
Using power automate HTTP function, I have been able to change the 'Created By' and 'Modified By' to the actual item submitter. But it is still sending emails from the rules as though I have created them.

It is by design: your user runs the flow which creates the Sharepoint list item, so you'll be the Author of the item. Workaround could be if you creates an other field, what you populate with the submitter user of the original form.

Hi Farkas, Using power automate HTTP function, I have been able to change the 'Created By' and 'Modified By' (or author and editor) to the actual item submitter. But it is still sending emails from the rules as though I have created them.
